# Does the transferred data section in chome dev tools calculates data transferred from service worker as well?

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am implementing caching using service worker in one of my web app/PWA, I am making use of service worker to cache the assets that I have also I made a long list of urls which I wanted to cache(they're being cached as I can check from chrome dev-tools applications tab) however when comparing both the versions of the web app - **one with caching in place** and **the other with no caching** - I am seeing no significant change in the data transferred section at the bottom of the **network tab in chrome dev tools**, hence the question, does this transferred data includes the locally transferred data as well?

this is the screenshot for cached version
[image]

this is the screenshot for uncached version
[image]

Comment: well first, 219 requests & 8.6MB!!! Wow, something I would look at first ;)

But yes, the bytes transferred does display what is returned via the service worker.
In your screen shots the first one shows there are over 30 requests not made the unprimed request does make. So that is your byte difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't really understand this statement though "In your screen shots the first one shows there are over 30 requests not made the unprimed request does make"

Comment: The first screen shot says 187 requests. The second one has 219 requests. That is 32 extra requests in the 2nd screen shot, the unprimed request.

Comment: Alright, got it, thanks

Comment: Do you have any reference for the first answer because I tried reading google docs about the dev tools but got nothing on it

Comment: I do know the amount you see cached in the service worker cache is the uncompressed response size. 
Just looking at an application I am debugging right now. It shows all the requests that were made and the KB/MB total for all the requests just as if the service worker was not there.

Comment: Yes, and that's what confused me in the first place